# Kettle transformation - Input file validation

Tags: excel, pentaho, kettle

I am using a Kettle transformation need to get an input excel file, validate it and save it to my mysql database.

Is there a way in kettle to find an input excel file is blank or not?

Comment: We need more information here for a complete answer. You can read an Excel file with PDI/Kettle. If you get no data, it's either blank or you did something wrong. But the best way to do it depends on what you want to do after you've determined you got no data.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file and use the "Detect empty stream" step.